# Conditional if it has some css

Tags: jquery, css

How to check if a div has some specific css?

Here is what I have tried without success:

```js
 $("#red").click(function() {
  
  if( $("#red").css("top") == "10") {
   $("#red").css("top", "100");
  } else {
   $("#red").css("top", "10");
  }
  
  /*
  if( $("#red").css("background-color") == "red") {
   $("#red").css("background-color", "grey");
  } else {
   $("#red").css("background-color", "red");
  }
  */

    });
```

```css
#red{
 position: absolute;
 top:10px; left:10px;
 width:100px; height:100px;
 background-color:red;
 cursor:pointer; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: A simple check of what `css('top')` returns in your console would show you why. .... `console.log($(this).css('top'))`

Comment: When you ask question,  you have to mention what kind of debugging you have already done, seems like you haven't debugged at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to check for pixels.
For example:

```
css("top") == "10px"
```

Instead of

```
css("top") == "10"
```

As for the `background-color`, `.css` returns it as `rgb`.

```js
$("#red").click(function() {
  var redColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
  var greyColor = "rgb(128, 128, 128)";

  if ($(this).css("top") == "10px") {
    $(this).css("top", "100px");
  } else {
    $(this).css("top", "10px");
  }

  if ($(this).css("background-color") == redColor) {
    $(this).css("background-color", greyColor);
  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", redColor);
  }
});
```

```css
#red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="red"></div>
```

**Edit**
I would take a different approach and use `css` classes instead of inline styling.

Here is a very simple example for this use case:

```js
$("#box").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('up')) {
    $(this).removeClass('up');
    $(this).addClass('down');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('down');
    $(this).addClass('up');
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.up {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.down {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="up"></div>
```

Comment: Also note `$(this)` is `$('#red')` inside the handler....no need to search dom for it again

Comment: You are right. Now it works. How about the option to check the color (in my example in comments)

Comment: @nrc don't be greedy,  you already have your answer,  use it to figure out your other problem, do some debugging  instead of asking others to write/fix your code for you

Comment: the color returned as `rgb`, a simple `console.log` can verify that. with that said, i would do it with `css` classes instead of inline styling.